# Borrar checkboxs al cancelar confirm()

Tags: php, html

Tengo una tabla con datos y unos **checkboxs** correspondientes cada uno a su respectiva fila. Si selecciono uno o varios **checkboxs** y pulso en **Eliminar**, me preguntará en un "**confirm()**" si quiero borrarlos. Si clickeo en "**Aceptar**" , los borra correctamente y si niego la pregunta, es decir, elijo la opción "**Cancelar**" cancela la operación pero mantiene activos los **checkbox** elegidos previamente.

Desearía que al pulsar "**Cancelar**", se borrasen los activos checkboxs.

Código HTML:

```
<div class="boton_eliminar" class="table-responsive" align="left">
     <font face="verdana">
        <b><input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="eliminar_cabanas" id="eliminar_cabanas" onclick="return confirm('¿Deseas realmente eliminar estas cabañas?');" value="Eliminar cabañas" /></b>
     </font>
</div>
```

**Código PHP:**

```
<?php
//Si pulsamos el botón "Eliminar cabañas"...
if(isset($_POST['eliminar_cabanas'])){
    if(empty($_POST['marcados'])){
       echo "<h4><center>No se ha seleccionado ninguna cabaña.</center></h4>";
    }else{
       foreach($_POST['marcados'] as $valor){
          //Nos conectamos a la base de datos.
          $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
          //Realizamos la consulta.
          $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana='%d'", $valor);
          $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
       }
       echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; URL=panel_administrador.php\">";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Con PHP ? Sería mejor emplear Js simple para esta operación. ¿A que te refieres con borrar ? desaparecer del `DOM` o cambiar el atributo `checked`  false.

Comment: Cambiar el checked a vacío, en lugar de estar seleccionado, que estén sin seleccionar.

Answer (score 1):

Esto se hace complicado si sigue asignando los `listeners` y las funciones a ejecutar en estos elementos directamente desde el `HTML` lo cuál no me parece del todo correcto.

Al cancelar o presionar la tecla `ESC` del `confirm` retornará `false` dicha función , dicho valor de retorno podría validar para asignar a false el atributo `checked` de los `checks`. *(No vería necesario PHP para esto , a menos que se me esté escapando algún detalle)*

**Ejm**

```js
//Seleccionamos el botón
var btn = document.getElementById('eliminar_cabanas');
//Asignamos el evento click
btn.onclick = function(e){
  //Obtenemos y asignamos el valor de retorno de confirm . true o false
  let option =confirm('¿Deseas realmente eliminar estas cabañas?');
  if(!option){ // Sí es falso
    // Seleccionamos todos los checks
    let checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    // Iteramos sobre estos
    checks.forEach(function(el){
      // Asigamos el atributo a false
        el.checked = false; 
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="boton_eliminar" class="table-responsive" align="left">
     <font face="verdana">
        <b><input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="eliminar_cabanas" id="eliminar_cabanas"  value="Eliminar cabañas" /></b>
     </font>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="5">
```

Comment: El problema que si añado tu código al mío adaptado, pues tengo un error: me vacía correctamente los checkboxs como debe hacerlo pero posteriormente me sale el mensaje de "No se ha seleccionado ninguna cabaña.", esto está en la parte de PHP.

Comment: @omaza1990 no tuve tiempo de responder pero la mejor opción sería emplear `ajax` así evitará estos detalles. Ya si entro luego a una pc quizá veo bien su problema.